# CT cardic Dicom MPR, asp.net MVC c# upload options

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, session-variables, dicom

my application is asp.net MVC3, I have developed a dicom viewer using image handler and it works well, now the challenge is CT cardic MPR images, some cases are more than 3000 images, I could not open them into the brower cache, I get out of memory error.  As a work around, I just open 10 files at the time; it works okay, but not with rotation (Rotate View anticlockwis earound chosen axis).  I am using the following script in the handler.

```
MemoryStream objMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
objImage.Save(objMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] imageContent = new byte[objMemoryStream.Length];
objMemoryStream.Position = 0;
objMemoryStream.Read(imageContent, 0, (int)objMemoryStream.Length);
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageContent);
```

My question is, is better to store the images in session variable, or store the images as binary data in a sql table to speed up the uplaod?  I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean 'not with rotation' and I'm not sure I understand the reasoning why storing in session or SQL would speed upload as at that time it's already uploaded to the server , so I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Adam, by rotation I mean Rotate View anticlockwis earound chosen axis. You are correct uploading was not the right terminology, I should used loading the files into the memory.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could avoid loading the image in an intermediary byte array variable and a MemoryStream by writing it directly to the response output stream:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
objImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This would reduce at least twice the memory usage. But I am not sure I understand the real issue here, what does ASP.NET MVC 3 has to do with your question and how does storing images in SQL Server or Session would help.

Comment: Thanks Darin, my application is asp.net MVC3.  Since I am not experienced in DICOM, I am just wondering if there is a better way to open the files and avoid the out of memory error.